# Press and release a key with Linux

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a little program that types for a user, using c++.  I've found the method `keybd_press(...)` but it seems as though that only works with the Windows header.  Any way to achieve this in Linux?  Basically what I want it to do is emulate a key being pressed for me, an auto-typer if you will.  I'd like it to be ran from the terminal, read the input from the user, and then type it until the number of times it should be typed is reached.  I can do all of that stuff, I just can't figure out how to emulate a key being pressed and released.

I don't think code is really necessary but this is what I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string mystr;
    cout << "What key would you like me to press? ";
    getline (cin, mystr);
    pressKey(mystr);
    return 0;
}

void pressKey(string str) {
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(str), 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(str), 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

**Note:** *I wouldn't mind using Shell for this if it is better, if it is an example would be highly appreciated!*

Comment: Please specify better what you mean by "key pressed". Do you want to make the X server think a key has been pressed? Should it work in a terminal, too? Maybe in a terminal only? Linux systems aren't so simple-minded like Windows that there is something like a global "keyboard input" queue modifiable from user space.

Comment: Added a bit more information in there.

Comment: Thanks. The question still stands: Where do you want that keypress to go? For example, your problem is solved by a simple "echo" in the terminal, but your complexity of approach tells me you want something else :-).

Comment: It can't just press the key by itself, it has to be in an application?  If it does it's for a game called RuneScape, which is a Java applet.

Comment: The question is rather: "Where should the keypress end up?" In your case, you would want it to end up in the input buffer of a Java applet. That buffer is processed by your windowing system (X11), so you'll have to insert it there. Now someone can give an answer how to do that :-). Sorry, it's just that complicated.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I guess I didn't realize that it was so complicated.  Thanks for clearing that up :)